# Getting Parse Username from other logged user

Tags: parse-platform

I'm making android app that uses Parse.com.

I have a subclass of ParseObject and one of the key (say for example "keyForPointingUser") of that object is some ParseUser.

I'm logged in as User a for example and in that particular parse object subclass I created pointing to user b. When calling

```
ParseObjectSubClass.get("keyForPointingUser").getUsername();
```

I get an exception

> ParseObject has no data for this key...

though I see in Parse data in the web browser that my ParseSubclass has a Prase User in the "keyForPointingUser" key....

Any ideas?

Thank u in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a bit late to answer but i've faced what you had problem here and i solved it with including user class to query :

```
query.include("user");
```